# Torque in a Central field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

If electric field is a central field then by definition torque should be zero but, then why does a dipole placed in a electric field has a torque working on it?

Answer (score 1):

Torque about which point?

Torque is not zero about every point .The simplest example will be  a satellite moving in a circular orbit ,the angular momentum about the centre of orbit will be $mvR$ which is constant. (so torque must be zero).

But angular momentum about a off centered point is not constant ,so torque is not zero :).

When we calculate torque on a dipole we calculate it about the middle point of the dipole ,and torque about that point need not to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a positive charge in a central field, the torque is 0. Likewise a negative charge.

If you put them both in the field, they exert forces on each other. The force is no longer central.

Comment: Still the force will be central ,after all the two charges will exert electric force ,which is a central force

Comment: I think the ans is that the torque about only some points zero ,not all points .In my ans i gave an example

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem for a system of particles which says that in the absence of external forces the torque about the center of mass vanishes, provided the internal forces obey the Newton third law in strong form. Electrostatic and gravitation forces obey Newton law in strong form. What you are doing is shifting the position where you are evaluating the torque.